# Cannot extract span element with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

See below. I am using BeautifulSoup to try and extract this value. What I've tried:

```
pg = requests.get(websitelink)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg.content, 'html.parser'
value = soup.find('span',{'class':'wall-header__item_count'}).text
```

I've tried find, and find all and it returns a Nonetype. For whatever reason the wall-header item count is unable to be found with these methods, even though it appears in the HTML. How can I get this value? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Two things:- 1) You're not checking the result from requests.get() 2) Assuming you get HTTP 200 response then just print pg.text. It may not contain what you had hoped for

Comment: Have you verified your element is in `pg.content`? If it's not, then you might need `selenium`

Comment: @AndrejKesely here you go: https://www.nike.com/w

Comment: @DarkKnight the request is working. HTML pulled in and I'm able to find other span elements, but not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get the number of total items. The number is stored within the HTML page inside the `<script>`. `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it, but you can use `re`/`json` modules to extract it:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.nike.com/w"
html_doc = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r"window\.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=(\{.*\})", html_doc).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data;
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print("Total items:", data["Wall"]["pageData"]["totalResources"])
```

Prints (in case in my country):

```
Total items: 5600
```

Answer (score 0):

you are forgetting to close the braces

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg.content, 'html.parser'
```

should be:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg.content, 'html.parser')
```